# Basic If Statement with String

Tags: objective-c

If I write the following function, I get a warning and an error on the third line.

```
int myYear (NSString *timevar)
{
if ([timevar isEqualToString:@"yr"]) {
    return ...
}
}
```

Xcode says

1. Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'If'...
2. Parse Issue: Expected ';' after expression

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Frankly, if you don't know that `if` in a C-based language is lower-case, you shouldn't be programming in Objective-C.

Comment: @HotLicks From another question by the OP it is evident that he is proficient in VB, making the origin of his confusion easy to understand: VB is a lot more "forgiving" than C/Objective C.

Comment: You are not using the programming language correctly. You have several glaring errors. I would strongly suggest you read some material on programming Objective C and work with some Hello World examples.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -- Perhaps, but his inability to interpret the error message doesn't suggest great proficiency in any language.  (Though I will give him credit for not saying "The If statement in Objective-C is broken.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `if` is a keyword, and keywords in Objective C are case-sensitive<sup>*</sup>. Same goes for other keywords, such as `int`.

```
// Use lowercase "i" in the "if"
if ([timevar isEqualToString:@"yr"]) {
    return ...
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> This is not a universal rule: for example, VB.NET will accept both `if` and `If`.

Comment: Oh, my gosh...  I can't believe it.  Thank you, dasblinkenlight.

Comment: @TBlue You are welcome! If your program compiles now, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it in a few minutes. This would indicate to others that you are no longer looking for an improved answer, and will earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is a case-sensitive language and all reserved words must be in lower case,

Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'If'...:
Parse Issue: Expected ';' after expression
  because you wrote `If` instead of `if` compiler supposes you are calling a function named `If`. hence it required a semicolon`;`.